# android- How to set 2 xml drawable for LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I set a xml drawable for this LinearLayout and I want to add another one to it .
this is the first xml drawable :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/blue" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/blue" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/white"/>

</selector>
```

This is xml layout :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

at this step ,I want to add a border around this LinearLayout , I've created another drawable layout . this is the code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <stroke android:width="3dip" android:color="#B1BCBE" />
    <corners android:radius="10dip"/>
    <padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dip" android:bottom="0dip" />
</shape>
```

How can I use these 2 xmles for one element ?

Answer (score 1):

You can not apply two drawable to a layout but you can achieve your requirement using single drawable only.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@color/blue" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/blue" android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/name_of_your_second_drawable"/>

</selector>
```

Comment: I did what you said but it says the code is unreachable and it didn't work . any other way ?

Comment: What do you mean by code is unreachable? What is the error message?